# When I click, function only works for first child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ı have a problem. I am desinging a cart page and ı get data from my server. I list data that ı get from server with array.map() as you seen in image.

```
  <CartItemsArea>
      {data?.map((item, index) => <CartItem key={item._id} dispatch={dispatch} setVisible={setVisible} productData={item} />)}
    </CartItemsArea>
```

and ı have three function in CartItem component.

```
    let reduceQuantityFunc = async (data) => {
    const quantity = {
      "id" : data._id,
      "quantity" : Number(data.quantity - 1),
    } 
    props.setVisible(false)
    await props.dispatch(reduceQuantity(quantity)).then((response) => {
      props.setVisible(true)
      alertify.notify("Sepet güncellendi", "success", 2);
      })
    
  }

  let increaseQuantityFunc = async (data) => {
    const quantity = {
      "id" : data._id,
      "quantity" : Number(data.quantity + 1),
    } 
      props.setVisible(false)
      await props.dispatch(increaseQuantity(quantity)).then((response) => {
        props.setVisible(true)
        alertify.notify("Sepet güncellendi", "success", 3)        
      })

  }


  let deleteItemFromCart =  async (data) => {
      props.setVisible(false)
     await props.dispatch(deleteFromCart(data)).then((response) => {
       alertify.notify("Ürün sepetten silindi.", "warning", 3)
       props.setVisible(true)})
  }
```

deleteItemFromCart works good in every child but two of  them what ı use for update quantity only work for first child when ı click, and when ı click the others childs again it works for first child.
[image]

```
const CartItem = (props) => {



  let reduceQuantityFunc = async (data) => {
    const quantity = {
      "id" : data._id,
      "quantity" : Number(data.quantity - 1),
    } 
    props.setVisible(false)
    await props.dispatch(reduceQuantity(quantity)).then((response) => {
      props.setVisible(true)
      alertify.notify("Sepet güncellendi", "success", 2);
      })
    
  }

  let increaseQuantityFunc = async (data) => {
    const quantity = {
      "id" : data._id,
      "quantity" : Number(data.quantity + 1),
    } 
      props.setVisible(false)
      await props.dispatch(increaseQuantity(quantity)).then((response) => {
        props.setVisible(true)
        alertify.notify("Sepet güncellendi", "success", 3)        
      })

  }


  let deleteItemFromCart =  async (data) => {
      props.setVisible(false)
     await props.dispatch(deleteFromCart(data)).then((response) => {
       alertify.notify("Ürün sepetten silindi.", "warning", 3)
       props.setVisible(true)})
  }
  


  return (
    <CartItemContainer>
      <CartItemWrapper>
        <ProductImageContainer>
          <ProductImage
            src={
              props.productData.product.coverImage
            }
          ></ProductImage>
        </ProductImageContainer>
        <ProductInfo>
          <ProductTitle>{props.productData.product.title}</ProductTitle>
          <ProductSize>Beden: {props.productData.size}</ProductSize>
          <ProductColor>Renk: {props.productData.product.color}</ProductColor>
        </ProductInfo>
        <IncreaseOrReduce>
        <AiOutlineMinus style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => reduceQuantityFunc(props.productData)} />
          <Unit>{props.productData.quantity}</Unit>
          <AiOutlinePlus style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => increaseQuantityFunc(props.productData)} />
        </IncreaseOrReduce>
        <Prices>
          <NormalPrice>{(props.productData.quantityPrice * props.productData.quantity).toFixed(2)} TL</NormalPrice>
          <DiscountedPrice>{props.productData.price} TL</DiscountedPrice>
        </Prices>
        <Delete onClick={() => deleteItemFromCart(props.productData._id)}>
          <AiOutlineClose style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
        </Delete>
      </CartItemWrapper>
    </CartItemContainer>
  );
};







     const Cart = () => {
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
      const data = useSelector((state) => state.user.userCart)
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    
     useEffect( () => {
         dispatch(getUserData()).then((response) => {
          setVisible(true)
        }).catch((err) => setVisible(false)).finally(() => {
          setVisible(true)
        })
      
     }, [dispatch, visible])
    
    const findPriceWithDiscount = (array) => {
        let totalPrice = 0;
        for (const items in array) {
            totalPrice += Number(data[items].price)
        }
        return totalPrice.toFixed(2)
    }
    
    const findDiscount = (array) => {
      let totalPrice = 0;
      for (const items in array) {
          totalPrice += Number(data[items].discount)
      }
      return totalPrice.toFixed(2)
    }
    
    const DiscountRate = (array) => {
      let totalPrice = 0;
      for (const items in array) {
          totalPrice += Number(data[items].discount)
      }
      return totalPrice
    }
    
      return (
          <Container>
          <Navbar />
          <TopCat />
          <Wrapper className="block">
            {visible ?
            <>
            <LeftArea>
            <TitleArea>
            <Title>Sepetim ({data.length +" Ürün"})</Title>
            </TitleArea>
            <CartItemsArea>
              {data?.map((item, index) => <CartItem key={item._id} dispatch={dispatch} setVisible={setVisible} productData={item} />)}
            </CartItemsArea>
          </LeftArea>
          <Sticky boundaryElement=".block">
            <RightArea>
              <ConfirmCart>
                <NavLink
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    letterspacing: "0.5px",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                  }}
                  to="/sepetim/odeme"
                >
                  SEPETİ ONAYLA
                </NavLink>
              </ConfirmCart>
    
              <SummaryArea>
                <SummaryTitle>Sipariş Özeti</SummaryTitle>
                <PricesArea>
                  <ItemsTotal>
                    <ItemsTotalName>İndirim Toplamı:</ItemsTotalName>
                    <ItemsTotalPrice>{findDiscount(data)} TL</ItemsTotalPrice>
                  </ItemsTotal>
                  <CargoPriceArea>
                    <CargoPriceName>KARGO:</CargoPriceName>
                    <CargoPrice>ÜCRETSİZ</CargoPrice>
                  </CargoPriceArea>
                </PricesArea>
                <Line></Line>
                <TotalCart>
                  <TotalCartName>Sepet Toplamı:</TotalCartName>
                  <TotalCartPrice>
                    {findPriceWithDiscount(data) + " TL"}
                  </TotalCartPrice>
                </TotalCart>
              </SummaryArea>
              <DiscountCodeArea>
                <CodeInput placeholder="İndirim Kodunuz" />
                <ImPriceTag style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "#E26A2C" }} />
              </DiscountCodeArea>
              <ConfirmCart>
                <NavLink
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    letterspacing: "0.5px",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                  }}
                  to="/sepetim/odeme"
                >
                  SEPETİ ONAYLA
                </NavLink>
              </ConfirmCart>         
               </RightArea>
          </Sticky>
          </>
             : <CenterContainer>
              <ReactLoading type={"spin"} color={"#e26a2c"} height={50} width={50} />            
        </CenterContainer> }
          </Wrapper>
          <Footer />
        </Container>         
    
      );

};
```

Comment: Can you include a codesandbox link? To better clarify your question

Comment: I am sorry ı can't but ı can explain better clarify . I get usercart data from server and ı map that data with arrray.map and that map function return an cartItemComponent but when ı click increase or reduce quantity button, function only works for first child and when ı click the others childs' button again works for first child.

Comment: It is likely that there is a problem in your reducer. Could you post your reducers ? increaseQuantity(), reduceQuantity()

Comment: Definitely a reducer problem - the actions you are dispatching don't have the product id associated with it.

Comment: ı don't use any reducers or extra reducers for these process

Comment: but deleteItemFromCart() work good for each childs

Comment: you may have followed an erroneous pattern pertaining to increase, decrease quantity...

Comment: may you give any advice for me bro?

Comment: After the first click on the first component, did you check your console for any error?

Comment: dispatch(reduceQuantity(quantity)), this function reduceQuantity can I have a look at that ? you're probably mapping your state and trying to update the quantity of matched ids...

Comment: @IsiakaLukmanBamidele there is no any problem, as ı said deleteItemFromCart function works good every child but the two others only works first child

Comment: @emre-ozgun                                                                                                            


export const reduceQuantity = createAsyncThunk("product/reduceQuantity", async (data) => {
    const req = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/shop/ordersteps/updatecart", data, config)
    return req.data
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue. Issue was releated to my api, I tried using findByIdAndUpdate instead of updateOne and it worked for me in mongoose.